# How to remove react-bootstrap Carousel animation and make it move on click only?

Tags: react-bootstrap

I tried this temporarily but I want to permanently remove the animation:
*I am using the carousel to display blocks of text only no images

```
<Carousel interval={10000000}>
   <Carousel.Item>
       <h3>Text Content</h3>
    </Carousel.Item>
</Carousel>
```